# Pull Help Center text from special answers on Meta

Tags: feature-request

Why don't we pull the help center copy from special community wiki answers on Meta? This way, ordinary users can help improve the help center.

Comment: Ordinary users **can** still update the help centre text, just propose the new text on the per site Meta as a question and an admin can update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Help Center is a site's official guidance.  It should change after consideration, not as a side-effect of somebody deciding he wants something new to be on-topic so, hey, let's just edit my favorite topic right into the list.  Yes it can be cleaned up, but in the meantime it'll confuse or mislead people who go to the Help Center looking for help.

CW posts don't require much reputation to edit, and even high-rep users make mistakes or, occasionally, rage-quit.  A site's official guidance shouldn't be directly editable by users whose contributions might not be accurate.  Working out the content on meta and having a moderator push the text is sufficient, and safer.